# knn in R: Can columns of training / test set be categorical variables?

Tags: r

I am trying to use knn() in R and it works fine when the predictors are numeric variables but the moment I use a categorical variable as a predictor knn() fails with the following error:

```
Error in knn(train = data.frame(csa.training), test = data.frame(csa.test),  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In knn(train = data.frame(csa.training), test = data.frame(csa.test),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In knn(train = data.frame(csa.training), test = data.frame(csa.test),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Is knn() designed to accept categorical predictors or not at all?

My function call was:

```
csa.training<-csa_clean[csa_clean$RN_ind==1,c("Age.at.Surgery.","Sex.")]

csa_pred<-knn(train=data.frame(csa.training),test=data.frame(csa.test),cl=csa.trainlabels,k=3)
```

If I remove the Sex. categorical variable the problem disappears. The Sex. column seems clean, with no NAs etc.

```
summary(csa_clean$Sex.)
Female   Male 
   119    188
```

Data:

```
csa.training[1,]
  Age.at.Surgery. Grade.   Sex.
1              38      2 Female
> csa.test[1,]
  Age.at.Surgery. Grade.   Sex.
3              24      2 Female

csa.trainlabels[1]
[1] Alive
Levels: Alive Dead
```

Comment: Post your data please

Comment: @adiana Posted some representative lines. The full dataset is too big to post.

Comment: If the only categorical predictor is `Sex`, why not just code it by using `0` and `1`?

Comment: This would work
     `csa.training$Sex. = as.integer(csa.training$Sex.) `
    `csa.test$Sex. = as.integer(csa.test$Sex.)`

Comment: How do you calculate the Euclidean distance (or other distance metric) between categories??! **It sounds like you don't understand how kNN works**

Comment: @adiana, @paulstey. Please provide a justification for **why** `0/1` is a reasonable coding for gender. Why not `-Inf`, `Inf`? Or standardization and 1 sigma? 2 sigmas? etc?

Comment: One approach is to use a random forest proximity matrix to compute nearest neighbors for non-normal data like this. The distance metric is how many terminal nodes two records have in common.

Comment: @Alex Any codification for a binary variable is valid.

Comment: @paulstey Sure, I can. It just adds a step. I'm just checking whether I must do that mapping explicitly.

Comment: @Alex Yes, maybe I'm using the wrong algo after all.

Comment: @Alex The question of using `0/1` or any other binary representation is clearly off-topic. He was just looking for a way to implement `knn` on binary variables and the `0/1` coding is one of the way to go.

Comment: @adiana It is not off topic. kNN is based on distances between observations. Using 0/1 implies a distance of 1 between categories in a particular dimension, which is clearly a fiction. Using such a coding scheme will give erroneous results.

Comment: @Alex Hastie and Tibshirani suggest using a distance function of 0 if two elements are in the same class and 1 otherwise for categorical variable (p. 504 of Elements of Statistical Learning). I think they know what they are doing

Comment: @Alex The said "It's the most common choice" while you wrote "Using such a coding scheme will give erroneous results". They seem quite different to me, according to what you wrote it seems that using such a coding is always wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107579/discussion-between-alex-and-adiana).